# Accessing global variable from file included within class function

Tags: php

I am writing a PHP application based on a single index.php file that loads different files based on the page requested, using a single `Main` class. However, I want to be able to access this `Main` class instance from within the page files.

My index.php looks somewhat like this:

```
class Main {
    public function init() {
        // Initialisation stuff
    }

    public function runPage() {
        // Obviously there's more to it than this
        $page = "page.php";
        require_once $page;
    }

    public function doUsefulStuff() {
        // ...
    }
}

$main = new Main();
$main->init();
$main->runPage();
```

In my page.php file I want to be able to access `$main`:

```
$foo = $main->doUsefulStuff();
```

However, this line fails with:

> Undefined variable: main in page.php on line 1
>
> Fatal error:  Call to a member function doUsefulStuff() on a non-object in page.php on line 1

Is there any way to access the `$main` variable, or an better way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: can you please post page.php file code.

Comment: page.php contains mostly HTML with some logic. Nothing else relevant to the question other than the above line.

Comment: $page = $_GET['page'] . ".php"; require_once $page; Horrible code :) Where is the validation?

Comment: Using values directly from the user (or browser) is a security problem. If you absolutely need to do this then you should compare it against a whilelist and *only* use it if it is in there.

Comment: Edited for clarity to remove offending pseudo-code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code inside page.php is being executed in the context of the `Main` instance. You actually have direct access to `$this`. So:

```
$this->doUsefulStuff()
```

Comment: Hmm... does that mean that page.php has access to private functions and variables in the `Main` class?

Comment: @c.cam108: Yes, as the code is executed in the class context

Comment: @c.cam108 For all intents and purposes you may think of your code as being copied and pasted by the `require_once`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is really not the best of ideas, but that's a different matter. The thing you're missing is that the code you `require` is effectively pasted into the `runPage` method, and so the variables are scoped accordingly. To clarify:

```
//index.php
$someVar = new Main();
$someVar->runPage();

//Main::runPage()
{
    $someVar = 123;//local to this method
    require 'file.php';
}

//include/require file:
echo $someVar;
```

The above code will echo 123

If you want `$main` to be a reference to the `Main` instance in those required files, then simply add this:

```
$main = $this;
require 'thePage.php';
```

Or use `$this` in the required code.

PS: the initial pseudo-code you posted contained something like `$page = $_GET['page'] . ".php";`. In someone has code like this: that's just asking for security issues. Think what could happen if `$_GET['page']` were something like:

```
/etc/passwd #
```

You're requiring `/etc/passwd`!

Comment: "not the best of ideas" - what would you suggest? PHP isn't my first language so my design considerations probably aren't the best. Also, there is input validation as mentioned in a comment in the sample code. I don't actually pass `$_GET['page']` blindly to `require_once`!

Comment: One of the things that made PHP successful is also responsible for its bad rep: anything goes. A `switch ($_GET['page'])` in your index.php file would be OK. A more elaborate, robust and framework-like approach is to use a routing system (look into how major MVC frameworks do things)

Comment: I've edited the question to remove the pseudo-code that everyone is getting worked up about.

Comment: @c.cam108: OK, I'm going to leave the bit about `/etc/passwd` in, though. Future visitors might benefit from it